# How do I construct a DLL using Visual C++ command prompt?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fatal-error

I'm trying to construct a DLL for below code.

**test.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>

bool _stdcall DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool _stdcall C_thread(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,SIZE_T dwStackSize,LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,LPVOID lpParameter,DWORD dwCreationFlags,LPDWORD lpThreadId)
{

    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD threadID;
    hThread = CreateThread(lpThreadAttributes,dwStackSize,lpStartAddress,lpParameter,dwCreationFlags,lpThreadId);
    return hThread;

}
```

First I try to compile it by using below command in visual command prompt.

```
cl /Zi test.cpp kernel32.lib
```

but it's showing following error.

```
fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

I need to solve this error by command prompt option.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow! We like to be helpful here, but I'm afraid your question is confusing. I don't mean to be critical, but it looks like you just grabbed a snippet of code off the web that you don't understand and you threw it at the compiler hoping that a dll would pop out. Perhaps you should take a step back, erase your code example, and just try to explain what you are hoping to accomplish. (By the way: creating a dll from the command prompt is going to be extremely challenging, even for an experienced programmer; is there a particular reason you can't use VisStudio?)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Basically I am linux user. Mostly working in command prompt is suitable for me.So, I chose Visual-command prompt.

Comment: Now i will come to my problem. I am creating Hook function for CreateThread(). But My mistake, It have errors. So, Just write a createThread fuction in DLL. By using my function (**C_thread()**) i will call CreateThread() function. For this, I try to construct a DLL. So, I compiled it. But it showing that **fatal error**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry point type is wrong: BOOL is not the same as bool (see [DllMain on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). This  is not Visual Basic but Visual C++.

You need to pass an additional option to the compiler to tell it to link as a DLL and not to link an executable image. A minimal example would be:

```
#include <windows.h>
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HANDLE hInst, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}
BOOL WINAPI MyFunction(int value)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

and compile with `cl /nologo /W3 /Ox /Zi /MD /LD test.cpp` to get a test.dll out. The /Zi gets you symbols in a .pdb file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer for my question. Below simple command will help.

**cl /Zi /LD test.cpp**